# Finding ellipses and distinguishing ellipses that are connected

Tags: python, opencv, ellipse

In the picture there are ellipses that I found but some of them are connected and `fitEllipse` found them as one and I need to split them into two

[image]

I have a problem when finding ellipses, it finds all ellipses, but I need to divide the connected ellipses into two, not one big one, I use fitEllipse, could anyone help me how to do that?

I need to divide one large ellipse as shown in the picture into two, they overlap but I don't know what algorithm to use to draw both like the others.

My code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 8, 70, 70)
ret = cv2.threshold(blur, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
contour, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(ret, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
minEllipse = [None] * len(contour)

for i, c in enumerate(contour):
    if c.shape[0] > 5:
        minEllipse[i] = cv2.fitEllipse(c)
        cv2.ellipse(src, minEllipse[i], (0, 255, 0), 2)
      
  

cv2.imwrite('output.png', src)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', ret)
cv2.imwrite('blur.png', blur)
```

Comment: You could check if the ellipses you have found have circularity defects. Search for similar questions on SO. If you need more help, please share your code and the original image, so others can work on it.

Comment: Check out watershed processing

Comment: please also provide source data suitable to use as input to your code. [mre] -- is this wood? are those bore holes made by pests? what is the goal? just counting holes, or extracting diameters too?

Comment: the surface is a CR39 detector and these are traces of radiation, I am trying to detect the center of each ellipse, minor and major axis and angle